# unable to disable future date in jquery datepicker

Tags: html, jsp, jquery-ui-datepicker

My application requires that the date picker should display the calender body on click, select date today's date being active and future date deactivated... i am new in jquery and it has disturbed me for a month. assist please. I am able to display the datepicker and choose any date upto 2030, but i need the calender to be active upto today's date or current date only. 
thanks in advance.

my calender to be displayed..

```
<table id="calenderTable" class="">
                <tbody id="calenderTableHead">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4" align="center">
                            <select onChange="showCalenderBody(createCalender(document.getElementById('selectYear').value,
                                this.selectedIndex, false));" id="selectMonth">
                                <option value="0">Jan</option>
                                <option value="1">Feb</option>
                                <option value="2">Mar</option>
                                <option value="3">Apr</option>
                                <option value="4">May</option>
                                <option value="5">Jun</option>
                                <option value="6">Jul</option>
                                <option value="7">Aug</option>
                                <option value="8">Sep</option>
                                <option value="9">Oct</option>
                                <option value="10">Nov</option>
                                <option value="11">Dec</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="2" align="center">
                            <select onChange="showCalenderBody(createCalender(this.value,
                document.getElementById('selectMonth').selectedIndex, false));" id="selectYear">
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td align="center">
                            <a href="#" onClick="closeCalender();"><font color="#003333" size="+1">X</font></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tbody id="calenderTableDays">
                    <tr style="">
                        <td>Sun</td><td>Mon</td><td>Tue</td><td>Wed</td><td>Thu</td><td>Fri</td><td>Sat</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tbody id="calender"></tbody>
            </table>
```

the date field is as below:

```
    <tr>
       <td>effected date</td>
             <td>
                 <input type="text" name="eff_date" class="required" id="eff_date"><a href="#" onClick="setYears(1947, 2030);
 showCalender(this, 'eff_date');" class="" id="calender">
   <img src="Calender/calender.png"></a>
              </td>
      </tr>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pretty simple to accomplish assuming I understand the question. You want to set the maximum allowable selectable date, correct? All you need to use is the maxDate option.

Here is a complete example, assuming you include the proper files referenced in the script and link tags:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>date</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link type="text/css" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="demo">
        <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
    </div>
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({maxDate: '+0d'});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can see it working here:
http://gigaloop.com/answers/date.html

Comment: thanks it is working, i was using a calender but now it is better with jquery datepicker. the only problem is now i can't change the year and i can only switch months in current year. Could please show how i can include the years in the datepicker displayed and also put some borders.

Answer (score 1):

You can use maxDate and combine with minDate:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-maxDate

Comment: i had this code and it is not working...:                        var dateToday = new Date();
var dates = $("#eff_date").datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 3,
    minDate: dateToday,
    onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
        var option = this.id == "eff_date" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
            instance = $(this).data("datepicker"),
            date = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, selectedDate, instance.settings);
        dates.not(this).datepicker("option", option, date);
    }
});

Answer (score 1):

Within script tags, write:

> 

```
     $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker-1" ).datepicker({
            minDate:"Now", maxDate: "+1m+1d"
        }); 
     });
```

You can change minDate to "-1m" if you want to show dates from 1 month ago and 1 month in the future. As per your question, you can put maxDate: "+1d" if you want to disable future days from today. 
1y=1year,1m=1month,1d=1day.